# starting script in screen

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, gnu-screen

I want to start a python script within screen from a script. I tried this

```
screen -dmS gateway_monitor;screen -r gateway_monitor -p 0 -X '/usr/bin/python /root/Gateway.py'
```

but if I reattach to the screen afterwards, it's just empty and looks like 
nothing has been executed at all. Any clues why this is or how I get 
achieved what I want?

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
screen -dm bash -c 'python your_script.py'
```

If you need several commands, use `;`:

```
screen -dm bash -c 'source ~/.bash_profile; python your_script.py'
```

---

Documentation:

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html:

> -d -m: Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_sh.htm :

> -c string: If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.